# Zeroizing a physical disk returns invalid parameter error

Tags: c, windows, winapi, filesystems, hard-drive

I am experimenting with physical disks using winapi. I am trying to zeroizing a whole physical disk i.e. writing null characters from 0th byte to last byte of the physical drive. This goes well until first few sectors of the physical disk but WriteFile() winapi method fails with error number 87 (i.e. invalid parameters). I checked the physical disk in disk editor and found out that error causing sector is the very same sector where my NTFS volume starts.

Is this documented some where that you can not write to sectors where volume data is stored? If yes then how can I zeroize physical disk?

I am running my process as an administrator.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: [Changes to the storage stack](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/942448) were made in Vista.

Comment: How exactly do you open the disk? You need to open physical device in order to be able to access the physical drive and not a logical partition.

Comment: You need to use `FSCTL_LOCK_VOLUME` before attempting to write to the disk.  This is explained in the documentation for `WriteFile`.